# How to check if a page load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my project, I run an URL. This url opens in a new tab. What I want to is the tab will close when that page loads fully. I cannot find how can I check this. Because the newly opened tab redirects to another website.

**mycode**

```
const shoot_3 = (a) => {
        const url = "https://j...g.com/shop/?add-to-cart=1575"
        var wnd = window.open(url);
        //TODO: isload? then --> alert
        window.alert("Add Cart!")
        return false;        
      }
```

Comment: You probably can't due to cross-origin security features.

Comment: I Don't think if you can. since the other tab opens in another domain. However `service-worker` might help.